# Got a 404 error on my JavaScript route

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play! v2 and I added a JavaScript method on my page that tries to retrieve data from the server. The client sends 2 information, a `deal` and a boolean (`withDebug`).

My `routes` file:

```
GET     /:deal/tailLog              controllers.MyController.tailLog(deal: String, withDebug: Boolean)
```

I also tried that, without success:

```
GET     /:deal/tailLog?withDebug=:withDebug   controllers.MyController.tailLog(deal: String, withDebug: Boolean)
```

`MyController` class contains the following methods:

```
public static Result tailLog(String deal, Boolean withDebug) {
    ...
}

public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
            ...,
            controllers.routes.javascript.MyController.tailLog()
    ));
}
```

And finally, the JavaScript call is:

```
function tailLog() {
    var withDebug = $("#logs-debug").is(':checked');
    jsRoutes.controllers.MyController.tailLog('mydeal', withDebug).ajax({
        ...
    });
}
```

When this method is called, my application is calling the URL `http://localhost:9000/mydeal/tailLog?withDebug=false`, which is the URL pattern I want, but fails with a 404 error message.

Note that before I added the `withDebug` parameter, everything was working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should simplify your question. It seems to be just a Router problem (with boolean), not linked to JsRouting system.

Comment: I think so, but I wanted to put every part involved in this processing.

Comment: I undestand. If `http://localhost:9000/mydeal/tailLog?withDebug=false` throw a 404, you can safely ignore the Js part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Play 2.0.4](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/play-framework/boolean/play-framework/htaOk8U5bvs/qFlTVuGh88sJ), you must use **0/1** to bind boolean parameters (and not false/true)

A little update in your javascript should fix this error:

```
var withDebug = $("#logs-debug").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem. Changing the `Boolean` to `Integer` "corrected" the issue (until I switch to a later version of Play!)